# Prove that if $X \times Y$ is compact, so are $X$ and $Y$.

Tags: general-topology

For the opposite direction, given that X and Y are compact we start with taking $O$ to be an open cover for $X \times Y$. Then for each $x \in X$, ${x} \times Y$ is compact. Later to conclude that the union of open sets $O_x$ is open and for each $x \in X$ there exists an open $W_x$ $\subset X$ such that $W_x \times Y$ is covered by $O_x$. 
Along those lines... but how do I go backwards?

Comment: The answer below gives a more elegant solution, but starting with an open cover of $X$, what is the only open cover of $X\times Y$ that comes to mind that can be created from it?

Answer (score 5):

The projection map into the individual spaces/components is a continuous map, so that it sends compact to compact.

Comment: And one sees nicely that an assumption is missing in the claim, which is wrong as stated.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: For each space to be the image of the projection map, all spaces must be non-empty. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @StefanH Exactly.